# How to select no of clients with today birthday?

Tags: php, mysql, count, row

I am trying to count num rows of clients with today's birthday.
The problem is, I don't know how I can remove Y from the query (client_dob Format is 1995-12-28)
I trying to achieve this using this code:

```
$stmt = $con->query("SELECT * FROM  clients WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(),'client_dob')");
  echo(mysqli_num_rows($stmt));
$stmt->close();
```

Any simple solution?

Comment: What do you mean by `remove Y from the query`?

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy Well, birthdays happen every year, right?

Comment: @Strawberry ah, he meant the year by `Y`, I'd misunderstood

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy means query to match M and D, not Y.

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy yeah! M = month D = day Y = Year.
strawberry, yes! it does :D

Comment: @Strawberry, any simple query you know?

Comment: `mysqli_num_rows($stmt)` doesn't count the records in the database. It counts rows returned to PHP. You are looking for SQL's `COUNT(*)`

Comment: @Dharman, yeah i know but doesn't it solve the result requirement?

Comment: Found Solution `WHERE DATE_FORMAT(client_dob,'%m-%d') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%m-%d')`